# REST API - How to structure endpoint urls

Tags: web-services, api-design, endpoint, rest

I am creating a REST API and I'm having some doubts on how to organize the urls for the following endpoints:

- list all universities
- list all faculties of a given university
- retrieve details for a faculty/university

I think it would make sense to have something like this (although the last one has an unnecessary parameter, *inst_id*, that I decided to have there for readability purposes):

```
#list all universities
/api​/v1​/universities     

#retrieve university detail
/api/v1/universities/{inst_id}

#list faculties of a university
/api/v1/universities/{inst_id}/faculties     

#retrieve details of a faculty
/api/v1/universities/{inst_id}/faculties/{inst_unit_id}
```

The problem with this is that university and faculty details are given by the same service, so it doesn't make sense to have two urls.

How should I organize this then? I think these two options are ok:

- Retrieves faculty details with the university url. This is good because there are no unnecessary parameters, but it kind of "goes back" in the route to get the faculty details after listing all faculties:

```
    #list all universities
    /api​/v1​/universities     
    
    #retrieve university/faculty detail
    /api/v1/universities/{inst_id}
    
    #list faculties of a university
    /api/v1/universities/{inst_id}/faculties
```

- Retrieves university details with the faculty url. I think the flow is more understandable this way, it doesn't "go back" in the route. However, the last endpoint receives an unnecessary parameter and the university details url is not immediately after the list of universities url in the route:

```
    #list all universities
    /api​/v1​/universities     
    
    #list faculties of a university
    /api/v1/universities/{inst_id}/faculties

    #retrieve university/faculty detail
    /api/v1/universities/{inst_id}/faculties/{inst_unit_id}
```

Which one should I use? Are there any other suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> There is no such thing as a REST endpoint. -- [Fielding, 2018](https://twitter.com/fielding/status/1052976631374000128)

REST has [resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1).  A common example of a REST resource is a *web page*; for example, the one you are reading right now.

The design question you are facing here is analogous to the question of whether the "university" web page should include the list of faculty, or not.  Either way is *fine*.

If you are using a media type with processing rules that have an understanding of [fragments](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.5) (HTML, for example), then you can provide an identifier for the faculty list as a secondary resource:

```
/api/v1/universities/{inst_id}#faculty
```

The choice between one web page or two is likely to be a matter of considering different trade offs.  For example, if the "university" part of the web page is much bigger than the "faculty" part, and changes more slowly than the "faculty" part, then you might consider separating them so that you can assign different [caching](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234) meta data to the two parts.